# optional match multiple strings

Tags: c#, regex

So I have the following strings:

```
192.168.1.254... 0000 0000 0010 = Flags: 0x002 (SYN)445
192.168.1.254... 0000 0000 0010 = Flags: 0x002 (SYN,ACK)445
192.168.1.254... 0000 0000 0010 = Flags: 0x002 (SYN,ACK,PSH)445
```

I am trying to create a Regex that will match all of these strings and I am trying to separate certain content. I have currently created the following Regex.

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*Flags:\s\d{1}x\d{3}\s\((?<flag>\w+)\)(?<port>\d+)");
```

This gives me ip = `192.168.1.254`, flag = `SYN` and port = `445`.
However this will only match the first string. I want the flag part to contain `SYN` - `SYN,ACK` - `SYN,ACK,PSH` maybe even a fourth such as `SYN,ACK,PSH,URG`.

I have tried looking at optional regex (but cant get it to work) such as:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*Flags:\s\d{1}x\d{3}\s\((?<flag>[\w,]+)\)(?<port>\d+)");
```

or creating multiple regex to match each one individually (this hinders the rest of the program).

I think making the ACK,PSH parts optional but I can't get it to work.

Comment: There are a variety of RegEx testing tools on the Web. [This](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) one allows you to specify the .NET RegEx engine. Fiddle about with a few of them and find one that will let you quickly test and refine your expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this awesome regex tester](http://regexpal.com/), I found that

((?:\d{1,3}.){4}).. (?:(?:\d){4} ){3}= Flags: \dx\d{3} ((?:(\w{3}),?)+)(\d+)

Fits your needs. Be sure to play with the Multiline option and use the .Matches member.

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex is close. The problem lies in the `flag` group: `\w+` matches `SYN`, but it breaks at the comma in `SYN,ACK` or `SYN,ACK,PSH`.

You can fix this by adding an optional, uncaptured group that includes the comma, like so:

```
                                                                changes
                                                               vvvvvvvvv
(?<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*Flags:\s\dx\d{3}\s\((?<flag>\w+(?>,\w+)*)\)(?<port>\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this.

```
(?<flag>\w+)
```

With

```
((?<flag>\w+),?)+
```

Explanation

```
(?<flag>\w+) -> take word
,?           -> optional comma
()+          -> at least 1 flag
```

When you use `Matches` you will get 3 matches and to take all flags, you can use `Captures`.

```
var regexPattern = @"(?<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*Flags:\s\d{1}x\d{3}\s\(((?<flag>\w+),?)+\)(?<port>\d+)";
var pattern = new Regex(regexPattern);
var matches = pattern.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var ip = match.Groups["ip"].Value;
    var port = match.Groups["port"].Value;
    var flags = match.Groups["flag"].Captures
        .Cast<Capture>()
        .Select(c => c.Value)
        .ToArray();        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Yuliam, I have tried your option above and it provides the following results.
Using:

`string dst = "DST IP: " + ip + "  DST Port: " + port + "  Flag used: " + flags;` 

I get System.String[] for flags.

When I use:

`string dst = "DST IP: " + ip + "  DST Port: " + port + "  Flag used: " + flags;`

With -
`string.Join(",", flags);`
I get the first value but no others.

Comment: @Taz, the `string.Join(",", flags)` is correct, probably you debug on the first match `0x002 (SYN)445` that doesn't contain more than one flag, if the input is the line that contains `0x002 (SYN,ACK,PSH)445`, it should get 3 flags, here is the [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iU9L2a)

Comment: The dilemma is that I have a source of data which contains multiple different strings which could look like any ones mentioned above. I need to get the data (ip, port and flags) for each of them. No matter how many flags are present. As the first match that it comes across is a single flag string (SYN) it misses out the other strings (with multiple flags). Any ideas?

Comment: After looking at your demo I think it has to be something else my end.

Comment: Could it be that the 1's move around eg.

`0000 0000 0100     0000 0010 0100       0000 0010 0000`

or that the flag value changes

`0x012     0x002      0x011`

Comment: @Taz, based on your latest comment, the pattern needs to update the flag hexa number too, [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TYGCED), if it's still not working, you need to have a definitive unworking reproduceable problem, if not this will just become ineffective long discussion